# How to correct this cached function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a cached function but even after storing the cached value in a variable, it always triggers the condition of result not being cached.

In my code, I have stored the result in the variable cachedValue.
The function that I am supposed to cache ('foo') should only be called if a new value in the argument ('arg') is passed

```
function cacheFunction(foo) {
  const cachedValue = [];
  return (arg) => {
    if (cachedValue[arg]) {
      return cachedValue[arg];
    }
    cachedValue[arg] = foo(arg);
    return cachedValue[arg];
  };
}

export { cacheFunction };
```

Test  Code

```
import { cacheFunction } from './cacheFunction';

describe('cacheFunction', () => {
  it('should cache function results and not rerun the original callback if the same arguments are presented', () => {
    const foo = jest.fn();
    const myCachedFunction = cacheFunction(foo);
    myCachedFunction(true);
    myCachedFunction(true);
    myCachedFunction(true);
    myCachedFunction(true);
    myCachedFunction(true);
    myCachedFunction(10);
    myCachedFunction(10);
    myCachedFunction(10);
    myCachedFunction(10);
    myCachedFunction(10);
    expect(foo).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
// It is called 10 times
  });
});
```

Comment: for me, it's working. beside that, i would take an object instead of an array, or better take a `map`, which is type save.

Comment: `if (cachedValue[arg]) {` is dangerous. What if `foo` returns `0`? Or `""`? Or `null`? Instead, use `if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(cachedValue, arg)) {` But as @NinaScholz said: It only works if `arg` can be reasonably coerced to a string without losing information / causing false matches. `Map` would be a better choice. `WeakMap` probably better still.

Comment: You might want to try lodash's [memoize](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#memoize) function which does this for you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) works only with objects as keys.

Comment: @NinaScholz - Quite, probably a combination of `Map` (for non-objects) and `WeakMap` (for objects) would be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mock function is wrong. `jest.fn` without arguments just provides a mock function that returns `undefined`. You need one that returns something based on the argument it receives. Perhaps:

```
const foo = jest.fn(x => x);
```

Then, [as I said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997381/how-to-correct-this-cached-function?noredirect=1#comment94832054_53997381) this is unreliable:

```
if (cachedValue[arg]) {
```

What if `foo` returns `0`? Or `""`? Or `null`? Or `undefined`? (As, in fact, your mock function does.)

Instead, use

```
if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(cachedValue, arg)) {
```

But as @NinaScholz said: It only works if arg can be reasonably coerced to a string without losing information / causing false matches. Map would be a better choice, and using a WeakMap when `arg` is an object would be better still.

For what it's worth:

```
function cacheFunction(foo) {
  const cachedValuesByPrimitive = new Map();
  const cachedValuesByObject = new WeakMap();
  return (arg) => {
    const cache = typeof arg === "object" && arg !== null
        ? cachedValuesByObject
        : cachedValuesByPrimitive;
    if (cache.has(arg)) {
      return cache.get(arg);
    }
    const result = foo(arg);
    cache.set(arg, result);
    return result;
  };
}

export { cacheFunction };
```

Live Example:

```js
function cacheFunction(foo) {
  const cachedValuesByPrimitive = new Map();
  const cachedValuesByObject = new WeakMap();
  return (arg) => {
    const cache = typeof arg === "object" && arg !== null
        ? cachedValuesByObject
        : cachedValuesByPrimitive;
    if (cache.has(arg)) {
      return cache.get(arg);
    }
    const result = foo(arg);
    cache.set(arg, result);
    return result;
  };
}

function foo(x) {
  console.log("foo called for", x);
  return x;
}

const cachingFoo = cacheFunction(foo);

cachingFoo(true);
cachingFoo(true);
cachingFoo(true);
cachingFoo(true);
cachingFoo(10);
cachingFoo(10);
cachingFoo(10);
cachingFoo(10);
const obj1 = {a: 1};
cachingFoo(obj1);
cachingFoo(obj1);
const obj2 = {a: 2};
cachingFoo(obj2);
cachingFoo(obj2);
cachingFoo(obj2);
```

Comment: Note: Fixed an error in my version of the function when adding th snippet, so if you don't see the snippet at the end of the above, hit refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `if` statement checking:

```
if (cachedValue[arg]) {
   return cachedValue[arg];
}
```

to be:

```
if (cachedValue.hasOwnProperty(arg)) {
   return cachedValue[arg];
}
```

because each of these elements is stored as `undefined` so the the first check `if (cachedValue[arg])` returns `undefined` which is considered `false` in Javascript

I think it would be better also if you use an object instead of array for this purpose so replace

`const cachedValue = [];`

to be:

`const cachedValue = {};`

Comment: While that's a good change ([as I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997381/how-to-correct-this-cached-function?noredirect=1#comment94832054_53997381)), it doesn't explain the OP's claim that what's in their question doesn't work, as neither `true` or `10` is falsy.

Comment: I've tried the code myself, the problem is that the check `if (cachedValue[arg])`returns `undefined` which is considered `false`